# Log Silverlight Error at Service

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

i have a silverlight application and one WCF Service.

i want to log all the silverlight application error at server side as a xml file. i have been tryed to call service in `Application_UnhandledException` in `App.xaml.cs` but not getting success,even service will not call. is their any another way to log my Errors Which is call when the error occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good example for server-side logging from the Silverlight client, using service methods

[Handling Error](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/12/22/silverlight-exception-handling-using-wcf-ria-services-and-wcf-services.aspx)

Comment: hello Sajeetharan can you Please give me a link or brief for your solution